# Export array data from MATLAB to C#

Tags: c#, matlab

is it possible to export an array from MATLAB to C# directly, without the need to copying and pasting the value in C#?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB has a COM automation interface that will let you control an instance of MATLAB programmatically from a .NET program and has functions named PutFullMatrix and GetFullMatrix that facilitate transferring a matrix from C# to MATLAB or vice versa.  See the External Interfaces section of the MATLAB manual for details.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f135590.html#f135616

Answer (score 1):

I would just save the array to a text file in MATLAB and read in the text file from C#.